# Set localprovider property of syncagent

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm practicing with an example given in msdn (Walkthrough: Executing synchronization[sql express]).

I could not find *syncorchestrator* as I'm using ms syncsdk version 2.1. Instead of syncorchestrator I'm using syncagent. How can I set the localprovider property for syncagent?

when i add reference Microsoft.Syncronization , in properties i found 
runtime version:v2.0.50727 and version:3.1.0.0.

Am i adding sufficient assemblies to have access to SyncOrchestrator class?

**EDIT**
I have included following assemblies:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Synchronization;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.Server;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer;         
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe;
```

Answer (score 0):

SyncOrchestrator should be in v2.1. are you sure you're referencing the right assemblies?

the Sync Agent should have a local provider as well.

have a look at using Sync Agent here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726015.aspx

Comment: I have included following assemblies:                           using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Synchronization;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.Server;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer;         
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe;

Comment: are you referencing from the right folder? when you say you can't find it, you mean you can't instantiate it? you might want to post your code